# Spring Data Rest - POST request return status 400

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jackson, spring-data-rest

After updating Spring Boot from version 1.5 to 2.7, POST requests returns status 400.

I have Feed repository:

```
interface FeedRepository : PagingAndSortingRepository<Feed, Long> { 
// Custom methods 
}
```

Spring Data Rest generate default controller for him, so I can make requests on: localhost:8080/api/feeds

Feed class:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("feed")
class Feed(
    id: Long, //Superclass Fields,

    @ManyToOne
    val parent: Feed?,

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = [CascadeType.REMOVE])
    val children: List<Feed>,

    @Column(name = "extension_id")
    var extensionId: String?,

    @Column(name = "create_date")
    var created: Date = Calendar.getInstance().time

) : Resource(id, //Superclass Fields)
```

Resource class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes(value = [
// SubTypes
JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Feed::class, name = "feed"),
])
abstract class Resource(

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    override val id: Long,

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "resource_tags",
            joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "resource_id")],
            inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")]
    )
    val tags: Set<Tag> = Collections.emptySet(),

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "resource", cascade = [CascadeType.REMOVE])
    val menuItems: List<Menu> = ArrayList(0),

    // Another Fields
)
```

ObjectMapper Bean:

```
@Bean(name = arrayOf("OBJECT_MAPPER_BEAN"))
fun jsonObjectMapper(): ObjectMapper {
    return Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()
            .serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
            .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_KEYS_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS)
            .modules(JavaTimeModule())
            .build<ObjectMapper>()
}
```

If I do a save request (POST localhost:8080/api/feeds) with payload:

```
{
  "type": "packages.Feed",
  "parent": "https://localhost:8080/api/feeds/251",
  "extensionId": null,
  "title": {
    "localizedStrings": [
        "https://localhost:8080/api/localizedStrings/4319"
    ]
  }
}
```

I get status 400 and error:

> JSON parse error: Instantiation of [simple type, class Feed] value failed for JSON property tags due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter tags which is a non-nullable type;
> nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.MissingKotlinParameterException: Instantiation of [simple type, class Feed] value failed for JSON property tags due to missing (therefore NULL)
> value for creator parameter tags which is a non-nullable type\n at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 10, column: 1] (through reference chain: Feed["tags"])

It looks like the Jackson library handles the request body a little differently, since this worked before the update.

I tried to specify an annotation for the field "tags" in Feed class @JsonProperty(required = false), but it did not help.

Any ideas how to fix this? I would be very grateful for help.

Comment: Which version of jackson-module-kotlin are you using?

Comment: @RoarS. My build.gradle contains jackson dependencies:

implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.13.3'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.13.3'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.13.3'

Comment: Please specify what parameters are passed to `Resource` constructor call in `Feed ` class. Or do you only pass `id`? It's not clear what `//Superclass Fields` comment means.

Comment: @VitaliiVitrenko, The Feed class contained all the fields of the base class and passed them to the parent constructor. 

class Feed(id, tags, menuItems) : Resource(id, tags, menuItems)

Answer (score 1):

Some essential code is missing in the question, e.g. how the property `tags`, which is mentioned in the error message, gets its value. Most likely does class `Feed` continue like this

```
class Feed(
    id: Long,
    tags: Set<Tag>,

    [other code here]

) : Resource(id, tags, //Superclass Fields)
```

If this is the case, Jackson will have issues with constructing class `Feed` because default value for `tags` is missing (even though it's defined in parent). In that case, adding a default value to `tags` in class `Feed` should fix the issue.

```
class Feed(
    id: Long,
    tags: Set<Tag> = Collections.emptySet(),

    [other code here]
```

Comment: Yes, the Feed class passed all fields to the base class constructor, including tags and menu items. I wanted to try your suggestion, however this will entail changes in the child classes. I fix issue by added the jackson kotlin module configuration to the ObjectMapper bean.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by adding the configuration to the Jackson Kotlin module.

Now a ObjectMapper creating looks like:

```
@Bean(name = arrayOf("OBJECT_MAPPER_BEAN"))
fun jsonObjectMapper(): ObjectMapper {
            return Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()
            .serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
            .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_KEYS_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS)
            .modules(JavaTimeModule(), KotlinModule.Builder()
                .configure(KotlinFeature.NullToEmptyCollection, true)
                .configure(KotlinFeature.NullToEmptyMap, true)
                .configure(KotlinFeature.NullIsSameAsDefault, true)
                .configure(KotlinFeature.SingletonSupport, false)
                .configure(KotlinFeature.StrictNullChecks, false)
                .build()
            )
            .build<ObjectMapper>()
}
```

After running a couple of tests, I can say that everything works as expected.

Comment: While this solution works for you, IMHO this solution is just hiding a code issue, and makes it difficult to understand the code. BR